# python / mpmath - How to get the real values of a complex matrix?

Tags: python, complex-numbers, mpmath

I am trying to get the real values of a complex valued matrix.

```
import mpmath as mp
A = mp.matrix([[1+1j, 2+2j],[3+2j, 4+2j]])
```

I've tried both:

```
mp.re(A)
np.real(A)
```

but neither work.

I've also tried looking for information here but haven't found anything
http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/mpmath/basics.html

The first gives an error message: `cannot create mpf from matrix ...`

The second gives: `insufficient indices for matrix`

any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `A.re` or `A.real` instead?

Comment: they also give errors, `'matrix' object has no attribute`, does your suggestion work on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mp.re(A[0,0])`, `mp.re(A[0,1])`,`mp.re(A[1,0])`, and `mp.re(A[1,1])` all work, but you are right that `mp.re(A)` doesn't work.  For the time being you can loop through the matrix until you find a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just if anybody else is wondering: The easiest way to loop through the matrix is using the `apply` function of a `mp.matrix`.

```
import mpmath as mp

X = mp.matrix([[1+10j, 2+20j],[3+30j, 4+40j]])
real = X.apply(mp.re)
imag = X.apply(mp.im)
```